# php odbc insert chinese data not accurate

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to insert chinese data which is stored in variable got from `$_POST` data on a form.

so after submitting the form containing the chinese data, it was stored into a variable in this way

```
$chinese_data = HtmlSpecialChars(stripslashes($_POST['chinesedata']));
```

then include this to the insert query..

```
$for_insquery = "INSERT INTO table1 (cdata) VALUES ('$chinese_data')";
$insquery = odbc_exec($conn, $for_insquery);
```

On my case the value i have input for `$_POST['chinesedata']` is `妾板妾板妾板`
When it went to the MSSQL database, now it became `濡炬澘濡炬澘濡炬澘` which is obviously not the same.

before anything else, I have ..

- changed the IIS host's locale to Chinese PRC
- have included `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">` to the source code's `<head>`
- saved the source code in UTF-8 encoding.
- even tried `utf8_encode($chinese_data)` and stored it in a variable and replaced it into the insert query, but it even gave me much weird results.

Thanks in advance to those who could help.

Comment: try changing charset to UTF-8 and see if it works

Comment: it still gave me weird values on the ms sql.

Comment: what is the data type for this column ?

Comment: i even tried it in nvarchar, no luck.